# VB Can I sort multiple list boxes together using criteria from one list box

Tags: vb.net, listbox

So as part of a school project I am creating a program that uses a Public Structure:

```
Public Structure ClientDatabase
    Dim clientID As Integer

    <VBFixedString(15)> Dim forename As String '15 bytes
    <VBFixedString(15)> Dim surname As String   '15 bytes
    <VBFixedString(30)> Dim address1 As String   '30 bytes
    <VBFixedString(9)> Dim postcode As String   '9 bytes
    Dim Rdate As Date  '8 bytes
    <VBFixedString(1000)> Dim notes As String '1000 bytes 
    Dim p_homeIns As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_reMort As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_homemover As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_firstbuy As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_buylet As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_lifeinsur As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_criticalIllness As Boolean '4 bytes
    Dim p_IncomeProtec As Boolean '4 bytes
End Structure
```

where the user can create and view clients' information in a table format. This 'table' was created using 3 list boxes. I know there are probably a million ways that this could have been done more efficiently but that's just how I've done it. Here is the code for how information is read into each list box:

```
filename = "D:\temp\clients.txt"
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.LockRead, 1103)

    filelength = LOF(1)
    numrecs = filelength / 1103


    For index = 1 To numrecs
        FileGet(1, client, index)

        ListBoxClientID.Items.Add(client.clientID)
        ListBoxClientID.Items.Add("")
        ListBoxFname.Items.Add(client.forename)
        ListBoxFname.Items.Add("")
        ListBoxSname.Items.Add(client.surname)
        ListBoxSname.Items.Add("")
        ListBoxAddress.Items.Add(client.address1)
        ListBoxAddress.Items.Add("")
    Next

    FileClose(1)
```

and I have attached a picture of how this main menu looks. Is there anyway that I could sort the Clients by, for example, their first name and then the client ID and Surname and Address would also sort accordingly so that the information is still correct?

[image: Main Menu]

Comment: Are you sure you are using VB.NET and not VB6 - those `Filexxxx` methods are legacy relics of the 1990s as is that structure.  please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: Our teacher makes us implement these methods for some reason, I already know how outdated these are.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest abandoning the Structure and go with a DataTable bound to a DataGridView which is essentially how you want to display the data anyways. That away you can serialize/deserialize the DataTable to an XML file. Take a look at this example; all I did was create a form, add a BindingSource, BindingNavigator, and DataGridView, and I added a TextBox and Button to the BindingNavigator:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private clients As DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Create a new instance of a datatable
        clients = New DataTable("Clients")

        'Add your columns
        clients.Columns.AddRange({
            New DataColumn("client_id", GetType(Integer)) With {.AutoIncrement = True},
            New DataColumn("forename") With {.MaxLength = 15},
            New DataColumn("surname") With {.MaxLength = 15},
            New DataColumn("address1") With {.MaxLength = 30},
            New DataColumn("postcode") With {.MaxLength = 9},
            New DataColumn("rdate", GetType(DateTime)),
            New DataColumn("notes") With {.MaxLength = 1000},
            New DataColumn("home_insurance", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("mortgage", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("home_mover", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("first_time_buyer", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("buy_let", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("life_insurance", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("critical_illness", GetType(Boolean)),
            New DataColumn("income_protection", GetType(Boolean))
            })

        'Check if the file exists to deserialize the data
        If IO.File.Exists("D:\temp\clients.xml") Then
            clients.ReadXml("D:\temp\clients.xml")
        End If

        'Bind the controls
        BindingSource1.DataSource = clients
        DataGridView1.DataSource = clients
        BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BindingSource1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Try
            'Create a file if it does not exist
            If Not IO.File.Exists("D:\temp\clients.xml") Then
                IO.File.Create("D:\temp\clients.xml")
            End If

            'Serialize the data
            clients.WriteXml("D:\temp\clients.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Display any errors
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error serializing the data.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripButtonSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButtonSearch.Click
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ToolStripTextBoxSearch.Text) Then
            'If there is no String, remove the filter
            BindingSource1.RemoveFilter()
        Else
            'If there is 
            BindingSource1.Filter =
                $"forename = '{ToolStripTextBoxSearch.Text}' 
                OR surname = '{ToolStripTextBoxSearch.Text}'
                OR CONVERT(client_id, 'System.String') = '{ToolStripTextBoxSearch.Text}'"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Great alternative with a  good explanation however I would have to re-write a bunch of paperwork and my deadline wouldn't allow it. Can you think of any way I could sort it using the current situation? Thanks a lot anyways

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. I would recommend that you never use controls as your primary place to store data. It's much better to create a separate object such as a `List(Of ClientDatabase)` so that it can't accidentally be modified by users or bad code.

Have a read at the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) programming principle

With that in mind, have a look at the code below. It looks a bit different to your code, but I've added some comments along the way.

Also a good thing to get into the habit of doing, Write your methods so that, as much as possible, they do a single thing. Instead of piling all that code into a single method, separate it into separate methods such as `LoadData`, `SortClientListByclientId`, `ClearListBoxes` and`PopulateListBoxes`

```
'OK. First thing, this creates the list I mentioned earlier

Dim clientRecords As New List(Of ClientDatabase)

'So here is the replacement for your original method. 
'Its much easier to tell what it does :-)
Private Sub WhateverOriginalMethodIs()
    LoadCLientList()
    SortClientListByclientID()
    PopulateListboxes()
End Sub

'This method carries out the single task of reading your data
'into the list called clientRecords
Private Sub LoadClientList()
    filename = "D:\temp\clients.txt"
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.LockRead, 1103)
    filelength = LOF(1)
    numrecs = filelength / 1103
    For Index As Integer = 1 To numrecs
        Dim client As New ClientDatabase
        FileGet(1, client, Index)
        clientRecords.Add(client)
    Next
    FileClose(1)
End Sub

'Now that the data is separated from your listbox, you can sort it
'using the method .OrderBy which takes a lambda method as its
'parameter to decide which property you want to sort by
Private Sub SortClientListByclientID()
    clientRecords = clientRecords.OrderBy(Function(x) x.clientID)
End Sub

'As above, but by surname
Private Sub SortClientListByclientSurname()
    clientRecords = clientRecords.OrderBy(Function(x) x.surname)
End Sub

'As above, but by address
Private Sub SortClientListByAddress()
    clientRecords = clientRecords.OrderBy(Function(x) x.address1)
End Sub

'This is pretty self explanatory. A good reason for separating this
'out is so that you can re-use the code, and in future, if you want to
'change it, you only have to edit this one block of code instead of several
'if you use the code in multiple parts of you overall program
Private Sub PopulateListboxes()
    ClearListBoxes()
    For Each record As ClientDatabase In clientRecords
        For Each client As ClientDatabase In clientRecords
            AddClientToListBoxes(client)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

'Same again here there is a programming principle called "DRY"
'Don't Repeat Yourself :-) You can reuse this elsewhere now.
Private Sub AddClientToListBoxes(client As ClientDatabase)
    ListBoxClientID.Items.Add(client.clientID)
    ListBoxClientID.Items.Add("")
    ListBoxFname.Items.Add(client.forename)
    ListBoxFname.Items.Add("")
    ListBoxSname.Items.Add(client.surname)
    ListBoxSname.Items.Add("")
    ListBoxAddress.Items.Add(client.address1)
    ListBoxAddress.Items.Add("")
End Sub

'Finally - I added this bit to make an easy way of clearing the ListBoxes
Private Sub ClearListBoxes()
    ListBoxClientID.Items.Clear
    ListBoxFname.Items.Clear
    ListBoxSname.Items.Clear
    ListBoxAddress.Items.Clear
End Sub
```